# Javascript - Using a variable for an object

Tags: javascript

I have created a constructor, as the following:

```
var FunctionCall(callingObject) {
    if (decider <= 5)  {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
function Constructor() {
    var decider = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    FunctionCall(decider, this);
}
```

What I am trying to do is in the if statement, set part of the `callingObject` object to a  certain value. However, I do not know how to  do something like: `(the callingObject parameter).part`. Is it possible to do so?

I thought that sending `this.part` to the function, and in the function having `this.part` be changed  to something, but I realized that instead of it changing `this.part`'s value  to something, it changed the `callingObject` parameter to what  I wanted `this.part` to be changed to.

Answer (score 0):

```
var FunctionCall(callingObject) {
    if (decider <= 5)  {
        callingObject.yourpropname = ....
    }
}
```

All the properties and methods of callingObject will also be passed along

Answer (score 0):

The calling function needs to set a property on `this` and then pass `this` to your function.  You can then access those properties in the function you're calling.

```
function FunctionCall(callingObject) {
    callingObject.decider = 'New Value';
}
function Constructor() {
    this.decider = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    FunctionCall(this);
    $('body').text(JSON.stringify(this));
}

var m = new Constructor();
```

Outputs: `{"decider":"New Value"}`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7cvUZ/2/)

Comment: Well, that still looks to me like it won't replace `callingObject` in the `if` statement.

Comment: Logically, this seems to work, but it  isn't for some reason.